# How to deal with off-topic questions that cannot be closed?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, bounty

A came across [a question](https://serverfault.com/q/741484/214507) which looks off-topic to me. I voted to migrate the question, but got an error message saying:

> This question has an open bounty and cannot be closed

How should we deal with such questions?

Comment: Before asking I tried searching for "This question has an open bounty and cannot be closed", but got zero results. IS it really the case that nobody has asked this question before? Or is something broken in the search functionality?

Comment: Is something *not* broken with the SE search? For such things, I usually target Google specifically to meta.se or meta.sf

Comment: @Sven Searching for `site:meta.serverfault.com "This question has an open bounty and cannot be closed"` on Google also gives no results.

Comment: You are too specific :) `site:meta.stackexchange.com close question with bounty` works

Comment: BTW, since this is a generic SE problem, meta.se is usually the best place to search for this kind of problem.

Comment: @Sven I thought I had tried searching on meta.stackexchange.com as well. I must have mistyped the URL and searched meta.serverfault.com twice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can flag it for moderator attention. A moderator can then deal with the bounty and close the question.

Comment: Can.... Can I get the bounty?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what happens to the bounty in this kind of situation?

Comment: @Colyn1337 The user gets the reputation returned to them.